# How do I return a DirectoryInfo object consisting of numeric folder names?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, directoryinfo

I'm trying to query a folder and return only folders with a numeric folder name.  The catch is that I need it in a `DirectoryInfo[]` object.

I could do it like this (and it works):

```
List<string> subDirList = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                           .Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, @"[\\/]\d+$")).ToList();
```

But I really need something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                   .Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, @"[\\/]\d+$"));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `.Select(..)` to map it to `DirectoryInfo` and then use `ToArray()`:

```
DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                   .Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, @"[\\/]\d+$"))
                                   .Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x)) //convert it to a DirectoryInfo
                                   .ToArray(); // make the result an Array
```

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate an object of type [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and then make your query. The method [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the desired array of type `DirectoryInfo`

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(yourpath);

DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = dirInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                         .Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f.FullName, @"[\\/]\d+$")).ToArray();
```

**EDIT:**

In C# 7 you could avoid using regex with a simple `int.TryParse`:

```
DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = dirInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                      .Where(f => int.TryParse(f.Name, out _)).ToArray();
```

below C# 7 you would need an extra variable of type `int` for the `out` value

Comment: Directory.GetDirectories doesn't take a path, move `rootPath` up to the constructor of `DirectoryInfo` and remove it from the call to `GetDirectories`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanx for the hint, I was to fast copy pasting. :) included the necessary links